# Using "just" with 'present continuous tense'

Tags: grammar, present-continuous

Can I use **just** with **present continuous** as in:

> **Mother:** We are running late for dinner, where are you right now?
>   **Son:** I am **just** getting home.
>
> **Friend A:** Did you finish the last answer?
>   **Friend B:** I was **just** finishing but the examiner snatched my copy.
>
> **Father:** Have you finished your homework?
>   **Son:** No, dad, I am **just** starting it, I need one more hour.

Are these uses of **just** *grammartical* and *idiomatic?*

I am a non native learner.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, those are all grammatical and idiomatic uses.

Answer (score 2):

"just" has quite a lot of meanings and nuances in different contexts. Yes, it can definitely go with the progressive, but there is a point at which you must understand whether it carries a meaning clear to the reader or the listener.

I am not a native speaker, but in my opinion the first sentence is not quite idiomatic, but still correct, since "just" here may well be switched by "only" and carry the following meaning:

- I am only coming home.

This goes better without any extra adverbs.

The other two sentences are perfectly fine by me.

The "just" there says "exactly/right at the moment/at this very moment" which goes well with the portrayed meaning.