# What I have just been saying or what I have just said

Tags: grammar

Good morning, why "has just been saying" and not "has just been said" - Since there is "just" in the sentence there is not need for the progressive tense, are they equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

When asking about constructions is reccomended to provide either examples or the original context. That said:

> has just been saying

I can use the following example to give you the possible meaning:

> Arnolt has just been saying for us to not worry about he upcoming grades.

Arnolt started the announcement, I talked to a friend explaining what is his speech about while Arnolt is still talking.

> has just said

Subtle, but there's a difference.

> Arnolt has just been said to not worry about the upcoming grades.

Arnolt started and ended his speech, and I talked to a friend after the speech.

In above examples you can interprete "just" as **"simply"** (to wrap up the main idea of the speech) or **"merely"** (a rude way to describe the speech)

[Just a little more](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/just).

Regarding to the use of "just" only in the case of present perfect (you said it is needless to the progressive tense), [see](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/224658/using-just-with-present-continuous-tense)